# How to build the app with using Makefile in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, makefile

I trying to build the test app from [Readium](https://github.com/readium/swift-toolkit). I use the instructions to do this, but I don't understand clearly what I need to do, because I'm doing it for the first time.

instructions:

1. (Done) Install [XcodeGen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen) and the dependency manager you need.
2. (Done) Clone the project.

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/readium/swift-toolkit.git
   cd swift-toolkit/TestApp
   ```
3. (I don't understand) Choose a type of project to generate.

   - :warning: from the `main` branch only:

     - `spm` (recommended) Integration with Swift Package Manager
     - `carthage` Integration with Carthage
     - `cocoapods` Integration with CocoaPods
   - from the `main` or `develop` branches:

     - `dev` Integration with local folders and SPM, for contributors
4. (I don't understand where I should use `make spm`) Generate the Xcode project using the `Makefile` and your target of choice. This will download all the dependencies automatically.

   ```bash
   make spm
   ```

Please help me understand what exactly I need to do in order to build the app?

Comment: 3: you must decide what type of project you want to generate among the 4 available (3 only if you're in the `main` branch). 4: as you already typed `git clone...` and `cd swift...` just type `make CHOICE` where `CHOICE` is the project type you decided to generate at 3.